# changing colour value of drawings after set amount of time with canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web-audio-api

I've made an attempt at creating a simple audio visualizer for an mp3 track using canvas to draw/ animate circles in sync with the audio track using the web audio API.

What i've done so far:
[image: what i've done so far]

What I want to do basically now is change the colours of the circles at a certain amount of time (eg. at a different part of the track - the drop etc). How would I go about doing this? `setTimeout`? I had a search but could not find anything (and I'm still quite new to JavaScript).

Here is the full code.

```
// Estabilish all variables tht analyser will use
var analyser, canvas, ctx, random = Math.random, circles = [];


// begins once all the page resources are loaded.
window.onload = function() {
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha: false});

setupWebAudio(); //loads audio track

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // loop runs 50 times - creating 49 circles
    circles[i] = new Circle();
    circles[i].draw();
}
draw();
};

function setupWebAudio() {
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'rustie.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);

var audioContext = new AudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance (WEB AUDIO API)
//contains an audio signal graph representing connections betweens AudioNodes
analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(); // Analyser method
var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
// Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
audio.play();
}

function draw() {
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount); //Array of the frequency data from the audio track (representation of the sound frequency)
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData); //take the analyser variable run it through the getByteFrequencyData method - passing through the array
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff00ed";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //fill the canvas with colour

for (var i = 1; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].radius = freqByteData[i] * 1;
    circles[i].y = circles[i].y > canvas.height ? 0 : circles[i].y + 1;
    circles[i].draw();
}

}


function Circle() {
this.x = random() * canvas.width; // creates random placement of circle on canvas
this.y = random() * canvas.height;
this.radius = random() * 20 + 20; //creates random radius of circle 
this.color = 'rgb(6,237,235)'; //colour of circles
}

Circle.prototype.draw = function() { //Drawing path
var that = this;
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.75; //Transparency level
ctx.arc(that.x, that.y, that.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
}
```

Another thing to add also - where in the code is it setting the movement/path of the circles? As they are going from the top to the bottom of the canvas. Wanted to know if I could change this.

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

Instead of hard coding the circle color to `this.color = 'rgb(6,237,235)';`, you can use a global variable to hold the hue `var hue = 0;` and then use that in your `Circle.draw()` like this: `ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(' + hue + ', 50%, 50%, 0.75)';`

Note 1: by defining the alpha in the color, you no longer need to set `ctx.globalAlpha`.

Note 2: you don't need `this.color` any more.

As you say, you can use `setTimeout` to change the hue variable at a certain point in time. Or you can use the data in `freqByteData` to change the hue variable continuously.

More info about hsl color: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#hsl()_and_hsla()

## Question 2

You are updating the y coordinate of each circle with this line:
`circles[i].y = circles[i].y > canvas.height ? 0 : circles[i].y + 1;`

Which means: if current y position is greater than the canvas height: set the new value to zero, otherwise increment by one.